# Why doesn't PayPal sandbox webhooks works?

Tags: paypal, paypal-webhooks

I integrate PayPal into Android app. I want to test payments in the sandbox. At this time application logs show that test payments is success. I tried to add sandbox webhook, which have to send payment information to my server as I guess.

But I dont't get requests from PayPal after test payments. I tried to simulate webhook request in "Webhooks simulator". I've got the same result.

May be, I've got to do something to get PayPal webhooks requests at my server? Because I have notifications about all test payments in my profile ("Sandbox/Notifications").

Answer (score 2):

Notifications in your sandbox account profile is a simulation of the Transaction Email that PayPal sends to the account, which is irrelevant to webhooks events in this case.

Instead, you may want to check the "Dashboard" > "Sandbox" > "Webhook Events" and see the status of events trigger by the transactions.

Webhook has mandatory requirement on your listener script to be a secure url (HTTPS), so you may check the web server setups as well.

Alternatively, you are still able to use IPN to manage all call-backs for the RESTful API (including Mobile SDK) transactions, with the same approach on the classic APIs, see more detailed on [IPN instructions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)

Comment: We use Classic API at website and we have IPN, which works. But there is another problem. At the site we have form, which send custom variables and IPN sends them later. But I didn't find how to add custom variables for the REST API.

Comment: REST API has not yet to support `custom` field, but at this time you may use the `sku` field under `item` object to carry over your pre-defined item specific values

Comment: And optionally for PayPal payments, you may append your parameters `?custom=abc` after the `return_url` to make the carry-over

Comment: @pp_pduan that's helping me a lot - but, can you add a sku field to a paypal express button? I can't quite find out, for example, on the popular Paypal Button http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/.

Comment: sku is not in the classic button tags, instead you would specify an unique "invoice" field in there. JSButtons support that too. https://github.com/paypal/JavaScriptButtons#editable-inputs